# jQuery Intellisense Doesn't Work When Any Other JavaScript File Included

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

As the title says.  If I include *any* other javascript file alongside `jquery-1.4.1.js` then intellisense for jQuery ceases to work.  Any ideas why this happens? As always, I've had a good search around but without any luck, it should *just* work.

Cheers

Comment: Is this in Visual Studio? Doesn't work for me either (p.s. add the tag for what software this is relevant to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes IntelliSense gets messed up by certain .js files. In general there's nothing you can do except removing the offending part of the source using trial-and-error.

At least in VS 2008 SP1 you can use the can use the `-vsdoc.js` "hack":

If you include `other.js`, also create an empty `other-vsdoc.js` in the same directory.

Visual Studio will then use this empty file for IntelliSense, so that whatever harms IntelliSense in the original `other.js` will no longer be active.

That way you'll don't have IntelliSense for `other.js`, but at least jQuery will work.

Comment: You sir, are correct.  Empty -vsdoc.js files associated with any other js includes are required.  I wonder if MS knows about this issue?

Comment: Yes, they know: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx. Though this is not required per se, only if you encounter .js files which break IntelliSense.